# php country specific timezone

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a site that will be accessed in different countries. How do I make the time specific for each country timezone. For example Nigeria is GMT+1 while Ghana is GMT. How do I show time to be 6pm in Nigeria while 5pm for someone accessing the website from Ghana

Comment: Hi , extract users ip and get his geolocation using that. there are so many 3rd party libraries to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

You can see link: 
http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

and to use in you php code, you will use :

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Kiev');
```

or any country you need .

Answer (score 0):

There are several steps in this process:

1. Use GMT, otherwise know at UTC, in your code and database.
2. Detect the country of the visitor, either by IP, or user data.
3. When outputting a time you convert UTC to the local time of the country of the visitor (see the answer of Ghaly Saqqal).

If you have difficulty, with any of these specific steps, you can ask a question about that.

Answer (score 0):

The most popular (==standard?) way of determining the time zone I've seen around is simply asking the users themselves. If your website requires subscription, this could be saved in the users' profile data. For anon users, the dates could be displayed as UTC or GMT or some such.or

```
new Date().getTimezoneOffset()/60;
```

getTimezoneOffset() will subtract your time from GMT and return the number of minutes. So if you live in GMT-8, it will return 480. To put this into hours, divide by 60. Also, notice that the sign is the opposite of what you need -- it's calculating GMT's offset from your time zone, not your time zone's offset from GMT. To fix this, simply multiply by -1.
then use some ajax to set time zone of visitor